# Gradle dependency caching during docker multi stage build?

Tags: docker, gradle, build, dependencies, multistage

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM gradle:jdk13 AS appbuild
WORKDIR "/home/gradle/"
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle "./build.gradle" "/home/gradle/"
RUN gradle dependencies
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle "./src/" "/home/gradle/src/"
RUN gradle build --info

FROM openjdk:13
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
COPY --from=appbuild "/home/gradle/build/libs/frontend.jar" "/frontend.jar"
CMD ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=default", "/frontend.jar"]
```

My aim is to prevent gradle from downloading the dependencies every time I build a docker image.

The command `gradle dependencies` downloads all the required java libraries in case they are missing.

Before the first `gradle dependencies` command I only copied the build.gradle in order to only download the dependencies and cache them.

When I run the `gradle build` command, why does it want to download all the files again? They are already present in one of the layers.

I have tried with `RUN gradle clean build --info || return 0` instead of `gradle dependencies`, all the same.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable isn't set by default. You'll need to explicitly set it, and then copy over the downloaded dependencies in the next stage.

```
FROM gradle:jdk13 AS cache
WORKDIR /app
ENV GRADLE_USER_HOME /cache
COPY build.gradle gradle.properties settings.gradle ./
RUN gradle --no-daemon build --stacktrace

FROM gradle:jdk13 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=cache /cache /home/gradle/.gradle
COPY src/ src/
RUN gradle --no-daemon build --stacktrace

FROM openjdk:jre-alpine
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk --no-cache add curl
COPY --from=builder /app/build/libs/frontend.jar /frontend.jar
ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80
HEALTHCHECK --timeout=5s --start-period=5s --retries=1 \
    CMD curl -f http://localhost:$PORT/health_check
CMD ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=default", "/frontend.jar"]
```

Here's my [original Dockerfile](https://privatebin.net/?8b4759d1a9d576b9#BD1xQE9cjwGaT8uSj87382pBNeuBcqxkidwMkqzE5UCM). I've modified it for yours, but haven't tested it, so you can refer to the original if you're in doubt.